# unknown property in value

Tags: jsf

I am getting yellow lines under a few of my values saying `unkown property values`

```
<p:spinner min="1" max="50" value="#{printerSettings.p}" size ="1"> <!-- allows the user a choice of up to 50, this is more than enough for any situation, if needed this can be removed or raised -->
                        <p:ajax update="p"/>
                    </p:spinner>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <h:outputText value="Copies that will be printed: &nbsp; #{printerSettings.p}" id="p"/>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>


                    Double sided?: 

                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>

                    Paper Size : 
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{printerSettings.selectedPaper}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{printerSettings.selectedPaperValue}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu> 

                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>

                    What time would you like the printer to print out your work ?, please enter the minutes after midnight :  
                    <br></br>

                    <br></br>
                    <p:inputText id="timeToPrint" value="#{printerSettings.timeToPrint}" />
                    <br></br>
```

`printerSettings.p` works perfectly fine, they are `printerSettings.selectedPaper`, `printerSettings.selectedPaperValue` and `printerSettings.timeToPrint` that have these yellow lines under them, the strange thing is it pulls the information from the bean, so i get a default value of 2000 for time to print and the menu displays three options, why is this doing this? Is there something wrong ?

Here is my faces-config

```
   <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>printerSettings</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>richard.fileupload.PrinterSettings</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
```

And this is my bean

```
public class PrinterSettings {

//@NotNull(message = "Please enter a time to print ")
    private int timeToPrint = 2000;
    private int p = 1; //sets default value
    private int time;
    public String selectedPaper = "A4"; // defualts to A4

    public int gettimeToPrint() {
        return (timeToPrint);
    }

    public void settimeToPrint(int timeToPrint1) {
        this.timeToPrint = timeToPrint1;
    }

    public int getP() {
        return (p);
    }

    public void setP(int p1) {
        this.p = p1;
    }

    public int gettime() {
        return (time);
    }

    public void settime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getselectedPaper() {
        return selectedPaper;
    }
    private static Map<String, Object> paperValue;

    static {
        paperValue = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        paperValue.put("A5", "A5"); //right hand side is value, may need to change this later on to make compatable with the printers
        paperValue.put("A4", "A4");
        paperValue.put("A3", "A3");
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getselectedPaperValue() {
        return paperValue;
    }
}
```

I also notice in the bean I get a yellow line under the paperValue.put bit that says usage of non static variable during initialization

Comment: Do you have all of the necessary references in your project? Typically you can't instantiate static objects, so you may want to check out revising your code.

Comment: Yes i think i have, i used the MAP function from a tutorial, it is weird they get the values from them but still have this error

Comment: "the strange thing is it pulls the information from the bean" - That's a correct behaviour if you attach for example `p:inputText` to a bean's attribute, it's going to show you the attribute value by default and you'll be able to modify it. "have these yellow lines under them" I don't understand what you mean here but I see you are doing bad dessign practices, using a lot of `<br />` tags. Use [http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_panelGrid.html | `h:panelGrid`] instead.

Comment: thank you for the advice about the br tags, and yellow lines, i have netbeans installed and they are showing these errors up with yellow lines under them, this is the tutorial i followed for the map list http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-listbox-example/

Comment: @user2054949 do not rely on tools that could check the code, instead you have to be sure on what you're doing. Take at the tools warnings as something that is not right (or maybe is not right for the authors of the tool). This happened me a lot when using JBoss Tools on Juno, but once the code started running there was no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get warning `"unknown property in value"` because of wrong getter and setter names for your PrinterSettings bean's properties. For ***selectedPaper*** property getter name should be ***getSelectedPaper*** and setter name should be ***setSelectedPaper***. For ***selectedPaperValue*** property getter name should be ***getSelectedPaperValue*** and setter name should be ***setSelectedPaperValue***. For ***timeToPrint*** property getter name should be ***getTimeToPrint*** and setter name should be ***setTimeToPrint***.

The name of the setter should start from set + the name of the property with first uppercase letter. The name of the getter should start from get + name of the property with first uppercase letter.

JSF uses getters and setters to access properties of the POJOs.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination